# join two different json to a single json in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and I have some problem in joining two json objects to a single json object.

Here are my json objects:

**Model Functions**

Function 1:

```
function get_All_M_MNN($in_Name) {

    $this->db->select('tbl_A_master.mk_id');
    $this->db->select('tbl_B_master.mm_id');
    $this->db->join("tbl_B_master", 'tbl_B_master.m_id = tbl_A_master.m_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->like('tbl_A_master.m_Name', $in_Name);
    $this->db->from("tbl_A_master");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Function 2:

```
function get_All_Y_MNN($in_Name) {

    $this->db->select('tbl_yr_master.*');
    $this->db->join('tbl_mm_master', 'tbl_mm_master.mk_id = tbl_mk_master.mk_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('tbl_yr_master', 'tbl_mm_master.mm_id = tbl_yr_master.mm_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->like('tbl_mk_master.m_Name', $in_Name);
    $this->db->from("tbl_mk_master");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

The first json looks like this:

```
{
    "mk_id": "81",
    "mm_id": "s1"
}
```

The second json looks like this:

```
{
    "mm_id": "s1",
    "y_stt": "1",
    "year": "2008"
},{
    "mm_id": "s1",
    "y_stt": "1",
    "year": "2009"
}
```

The mm_id is the same in both the json so the result json should be like this:

```
{
    "mk_id": "81",
    "mm_id": "s1",
    "year": ["2008","2009"]
}
```

which means the secound json should be in the first json with year by using the same mm_id

I have tried different things like `array_merge();` but no luck.

Comment: Try this json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($a, true),json_decode($b, true))); Will help at some extent. Or first decode them to pure array and play with them

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL query:

```
SELECT mk_id, mm_id, CONCAT('[', CONCAT_GROUP(year), ']')
FROM ...
GROUP BY mm_id
```

you should get sth like this:

```
81,  s1, [2008,2009]
```